# Sound not working - bug in a specific version of kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, audio, bugs

I find it rather hard to believe, but since I installed kernel:

> 4.15.0-**58**

several days ago, my sound on Linux Mint 19.2 Cinnamon stopped working, and no matter what I tried like:

```
sudo apt reinstall alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo alsa force-reload
```

- 

```
reboot(-s)
```

- 

```
alsamixer
```

nothing brought me sound back, so I just installed an older kernel, namely the littlest bit older one:

> 4.15.0-**55**

now everything works like a charm.

---

How can I debug this and figure out if the problem is a bug in the kernel itself or in some other audio-related package? I don't know what exact information you could require for this, so please ask in the comment section, I will answer eventually.

---

I have just reproduced the problem by upgrading back to 4.15.0-**58** from 4.15.0-**55**. Sound not working again. Plus, by switching to an older kernel proves sound is functional.

---

Hardware:

laptop Dell with service tag *==REMOVED==*

---

Bug report

submitted, thank you Stephen for the link, where I [have put all the info](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1840796)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because bug reports should be reported as such

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since downgrading your kernel restored your audio, this appears to be a regression in the kernel. Since you’re using an Ubuntu kernel, the best place to report the issue is [there](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux), but if you’re feeling brave, you could look at [all the changes listed in the changelog](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/4.15.0-58.64) to try to determine what could be causing the problem.

If you do report it, you should mention the fact that downgrading from -58 to -55 fixes the problem for you; you should also include the contents of `/proc/asound/cards` in your working setup, and the module you’re using (`lspci -v` will tell you). Ideally, you could also try the packages released between -55 and -58; I suspect that the regression is in -56 since that includes a lot of changes.